# Installing RelationExtensions for petapoco firing error

Tags: petapoco

I have installed petapoco RelationExtensions from NUGET and it`s firing error message:

> Error 4   The type or namespace name 'IDatabase' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\testkit\Models\PetaPocoRelationExtensions.cs   13

Is there the need to dowload any other files?
How can I correct the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the IDatabase references to Database references this will work correctly. Nuget has been updated to fix this in 1.0.2.

The IDatabase interface is available on my branch at http://github.com/schotime/petapoco along with extra features, like Fluent Mapping.